# Ajax : data retrieving in rails3 + formtastic

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have successfully tried ajax saving in my sample formtastic with ajax form.

The new value is added to the database. But the the problem is in retrieving the list from the database as soon as i save via ajax.

How to do it.?

As soon as I add a new record I want my displaying list to be update. Both the option to add new record and list the data from database is in same page

This is my Index page. The controller and all other created via scaffolding

```
<h1>Listing samples</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
<th><%=t :Name%></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @samples.each do |sample| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= sample.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', sample %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sample_path(sample) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sample, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Sample', new_sample_path %>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<%= semantic_form_for @sample1,:url => samples_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>

    <%= f.input :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the CRUD operation using these guidelines and it worked perfect

http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 4):

When you save via ajax, you may have to change the way your controller responds, kinda like this:

```
def create
  # stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

When you do this, rails would expect you to have created a file named `create.js.erb`, in which you can manipulate the data of your view(append new content to your table, render a whole new partial with your new object list, etc):

```
$('#your_list').html(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render('your_table_partial')) %>"
);
```

Or

```
$('#your_list').append(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render('your_item_of_the_table_partial')) %>"
);
```

These are just examples, i don't know your code enough to write the correct code for you, but you sure can use these as a base for your work.